# Cloning Ubuntu mdadm RAID1

Tags: ubuntu, raid, raid-1, mdadm, clonezilla

I would like to clone a pair of RAID1 drives created with mdadm.  I've tried Clonezilla, but there's no native support for mdadm, so it resorts to using dd which is incredibly slow.  I've looked for other options but none of them seem to have the ease of use of Clonezilla (and often require manual reconfiguration of mdadm which I'm okay with to a point).  I suspect I've missed something, though.

I have not yet tried breaking the mirror and rebuilding it with a fresh drive to see if it's faster than plain dd.

What do you use to create images of RAID'd drives?